# Use angular-cli proxy for multiple backends

Tags: angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

I had a first proxy-config.json that worked and still works :

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""},
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

That proxy my nodejs mock server. 
Now I'd like to test my `/api/myObjects` java server api entry. It's relying on other API still being developped.

For tests i tried :

```
{
  "/api2/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080/",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api2" : ""},
    "secure": false
  },
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""},
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

It successfully retrieved myObjects behind `/api2/myObjects` but for every other API, I get a 504 "gateway timeout".

I also tried the 3rd notation "Multiple entry" from the [Webpack-dev-server documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy) but i still get the 504.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. do you **need** `pathRewrite`? 2. please use `**` double-stars. 3. please remove the `/` at the end of your `target`'s eg. `"target": "http://localhost:3000/"` becomes `"target": "http://localhost:3000"` 4. stating the obvious, make sure your servers are both working.

Comment: Your configuration works for me. But I don't use `pathRewrite`. Try @AhmedMusallam's suggestions again.